# Jquery - Copy div contents to clipboard

Tags: jquery

I've a site that produces a dynamic table of data for researchers.  At the moment they need to select and copy to paste this information into whatever application they want to use it in.

Does anyone know of any way to copy data contained within a div / table to the clipboard using Jquery?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Copy to Clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few plugins out there for this, they use a very small flash video to do the actual work:

- [jQuery Clipboard copy](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/copy)
- [Clipboard](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at a jQuery plugin called [zClip](http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/). It is based on the Zero Clipboard library