# Copy and paste clipboard in JavaScript. or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard

How do I copy content thats present in a `div` tag and paste it to applications like Paint, Powerpoint etc.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery

Comment: You should clarify your question. Do you want to CTRL+C CTRL+V something or what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery - Copy div contents to clipboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308115/jquery-copy-div-contents-to-clipboard)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy text to the client's clipboard using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery)

Comment: It seems from your later comments you want to copy as an image, this should have been made clearer in the question.

Comment: This seems to be what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336102/how-to-save-specific-part-of-page-as-image-using-javascipt

Answer (score 3):

It is not easy but possible:

```
function copyToClipboard(meintext) {  
if (window.clipboardData)   
     window.clipboardData.setData("Text", meintext);  
else if (window.netscape) {  
     netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege('UniversalXPConnect');  
     var clip = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/widget/clipboard;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard);  
     if (!clip)  
          return false;  
     var trans = Components.classes['@mozilla.org/widget/transferable;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsITransferable);  
     if (!trans)  
          return false;  
     trans.addDataFlavor('text/unicode');  
     var str = new Object();  
     var len = new Object();  
     var str = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/supports-string;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsISupportsString);  
     str.data=meintext;  
     trans.setTransferData("text/unicode",str,meintext.length*2);  
     var clipid=Components.interfaces.nsIClipboard;  
     if (!clipid)  
          return false;  
     clip.setData(trans,null,clipid.kGlobalClipboard);  
}  
     return false;  
}
```

Please note. The first two lines are for IE.

All the following for Firefox.
And for Firefox the clipboard has to be enabled:

Open `about:config`
set `signed.applets.codebase_principal_support` to `true`.

Or just use some Flash-stuff :)

Comment: thanks but i need the content to be copied as a image not as a text.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [jquery clipboard](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard), check the homepage [here](http://bradleysepos.com/projects/jquery/clipboard/)