# undo, redo, copy, paste, cut with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible and if yes then how to implement undo,redo,copy,paste and cut with jQuery on textarea for example.

I did checked [jQuery undo plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Undo) but it didn't work that well also i tried to implement keypress by myself using jQuery extensions methods. Created keypress event and assigned value to it. Still didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475293/copy-and-paste-clipboard-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @Tim Down, i have some buttons on which user can click and undo/redo copy/paste/cut ... So all of the answers here don't even match what i've asked. Seems i cannot provide this functionally without heavy usage of Flash hacks.

Comment: You're right. There's no way of getting and setting content on the system clipboard in JavaScript that works in all browsers and security settings, which is a good thing from a security perspective.

Comment: @Tim Down, **feature removed**

Comment: @TimDown, what about undo/redo? How can I achieve this in jquery/javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/clipboard

[How to copy text to the client's clipboard using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery)

[Copy and paste clipboard in JavaScript. or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475293/copy-and-paste-clipboard-in-javascript-or-jquery)