# Mimicking modern browsers' copy url using jQuery (add http:// when copied)

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy-paste

I'm trying to mimic modern browsers' "copy url" functionality.

When viewing the url you don't see the `http://`. If you copy it to the clipboard, `http://` will be added. So far I have this:

```
$('#address input').bind('copy', function() {
  $.fn.changevalue = function (v) {
    return $(this).val(v).trigger('change');
  }
  var origval = $(this).val();
  $(this).changevalue('http://' + origval);
});
```

This adds the `http://` to the input field, if action 'copy' is detected but it stops the copy to clipboard. The function also adds `http://` to main input field, that I don't want. I just want to add it to clipboard.

Comment: Thank you Rob Hruska for editing my questions title and post, but next time please do not remove my t.i.a line!

Comment: The tia is implied, it, like taglines, just clutters the questions, I wouldn't be surprised if it actually discourages users from answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: JavaScript cannot access the clipboard.  Any plugin that does this usually uses Flash in the background.

To fix the copy event, after adding `http://` to the input, you need to trigger the `select` event (not the `change` event).  When the value is changed, the text is no longer selected, so you need to select the new text after it's edited.

To remove the `http://` from the input field, you can add a `setTimeout` to the end of the event to reset the value.

Also, you should set `$.fn.changevalue` outside of the callback, it doesn't need to be re-set on each copy event.

```
$.fn.changevalue = function(v) {
    return this.val(v).trigger('select');  // this is already a jQuery object
}

$('#address input').bind('copy', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
    origval = $this.val();
    $this.changevalue('http://' + origval);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.val(origval);
    }, 0);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TGHcD/

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any "copy" event in jQuery and it seems a bit tricky to make it work cross browsers.

See [this thread/question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539641/copy-text-to-the-clients-clipboard-using-jquery) for plugins and other ways to copy text to the clipboard. (Some use flash (swf files) to make it work.)

More information on the subject:

- http://help.dottoro.com/ljxundda.php
- [Copy and paste clipboard in JavaScript. or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475293/copy-and-paste-clipboard-in-javascript-or-jquery)
- http://bradleysepos.com/projects/jquery/clipboard/