# Copy / Paste clipboard iPhone using Phonegap

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cordova, clipboard

How can I get access to the iPhone clipboard whilst using PhoneGap? I cannot see support in their [docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.5.0/) so wonder if there is another way I can gain access?

Comment: You can do it with Javascript, with or without JQuery. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475293/copy-and-paste-clipboard-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this seems to be a Mozilla only solution and the jQuery plugin requires flash, which isn't on the iPhone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a ClipBoard plugin that you can try: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ClipboardPlugin

Note that this plugin supports copying and pasting only text and no other data types right now.

Comment: Thanks - I had literally just found this as you posted. P.s. any idea how to extend this for images?

Comment: U're welcome. I'm not sure how to extend it for images, but if you have access to objective-c code, just use the `NSPasteboard* pasteBoard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];`, then you can get the content with: `image = [pasteBoard dataForType:NSTIFFPboardType];`.

Comment: 404, what is the preferred approach in 2013?

Comment: page not found on github

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the current plugin for this functionality:

https://github.com/VersoSolutions/CordovaClipboard

Answer (score 1):

Link does not work. I found this other question more useful

[Copy to Clipboard with javascript for phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361345/copy-to-clipboard-with-javascript-for-phonegap)