# Copy url to clipboard sencha touch

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

[image]

Am using sencha touch to build an ios app, here i have a button "Copy External File Upload Linke", By tap on that button i need to copy a url eg:`/"www.google.com"` to device clipboard and later paste that url some where else. Is there any solution to do it ? Please help me to solve this issue, your help is much appreciated..Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361345/copy-to-clipboard-with-javascript-for-phonegap

Comment: Yes, but i didn't find clipboardmanager plugin in phonegap 3.0

Comment: I didnt find any way using sencha touch only. But you may do it as a workaround
window.prompt ("Tap and hold to copy URL", 'URL to copy'); It will alert a textbox with two buttons ok and cancel

Comment: With sencha touch only I think is not feasible because you cannot access the `clipboard` with JS only for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Cordova clipboard plugin for version 3.0 and upwards: https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/67

Comment: Thank yo so much for the plugin link..Hope it will solve my problem in Android..But am not using phonegap in ios build. Is there any solution to solve this issue in sencha touch way..

Comment: As far as I know you cannot access the `clipboard` in JS without some FLash solutions, which are not supported by iOS. I've looked also at the Sencha Touch packager for Native API in this sense but haven't found anything useful so far.