# Paste Text currently on clipboard in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web application. I would like to get Text that is on the client's clipboard currently and paste in the textbox on my web page. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: What does your code look like..? have you tried looking up `GetText` method of the Clipboard...? `Clipboard.GetText`

Comment: @DJ Craze: that will get the clipboard from the server, not the client.

Comment: Doesn't look easy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475293/copy-and-paste-clipboard-in-javascript-or-jquery

Comment: This seems like a security nightmare waiting to happen...What if somebody has something confidential in their clipboard?

Comment: @KingCronus, yeah figured this is why it was that hard but thought someone might have a solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying clipboard content through Javascript is dangerous and highly vulnerable approach. If you still want to implement client-side copy then you should checkout ZeroClipboard.

https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard

Answer (score 0):

All security freaks(of which I am one) seem to forget that there are web deployments to the intranet... and in this case, if you care that it only works in `IE` (and `Firefox` with an extension) you can use [this guide](http://www.daftlogic.com/sandbox-javascript-to-copy-paste-clipboard.htm).

To paste, with a bit of `jQuery` thrown-in for flavor :)

```
    $('.pasteHotspot').on('click', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();

         var pasteField = $(this).parent().find('.pasteField')[0];

         // Keeps the other browsers from throwing exceptions..
         if (typeof pasteField.createTextRange != 'function') return;

         paste(pasteField);
     }


     function paste(pasteField) {
         pasteField.focus();

         pasteField.select();

         var therange = pasteField.createTextRange();

         therange.execCommand("Paste");
     }
```